# Passing variable by name to right-hand-side of assignment := in data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I would like to pass a variable by name to a data.table X as follows:

```
myfunc <- function(varname){
  X[, newVar:= varname]
}
myfunc("oldVar")
```

How should I go about it? I have tried `quote()` with `eval()`, but it didn't work.

Comment: You really ought to work your way through the [data.table faq](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf). This one is FAQ 1.5 - 1.6.

Comment: Is `varname` the name of some object in your `.GlobalEnv`?

Comment: Are you simply trying to rename the column?

Comment: @GSee: varname is the name of a column in data.table X that has not been created as an object. Mnel: my example above is a simplified one. I know about rename, but that's not I would like to do here. Josh: thanks for pointing me to the FAQ. I tried quote() and eval() but it didn't work. I'll have another look to check if I miss anything.

Comment: @AdamNYC If it "didn't work", you should post what you tried and what the error message was. "Didn't work" is one of those famously unhelpful (annoying, even) phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up the column as a vector, and use that for the assignment:

```
myfunc <- function(varname){
  X[, newVar := X[[varname]]]
}

X <- data.table(oldVar=1:4, b=5:8)

> myfunc("oldVar")
   oldVar b newVar
1:      1 5      1
2:      2 6      2
3:      3 7      3
4:      4 8      4
```